# How add Code Coverage for system and integration tests ran in docker

Tags: docker, code-coverage, microservices, jacoco, clover

I am trying to add code coverage to my Java Spring project. The current integration and system tests run the micro services in docker and run tests against them when I run the tests.

How can I add code coverage to this architecture to generate the report when i run the tests on services in docker?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you using arqullian tests?

Comment: no we are not using a specific framework for our tests.

Answer (score 0):

Use sonarqube, you can connect it with jenkins and let jenkins be your auto builder

Comment: Thanks for your reply! would sonarqube provide code coverage reports or would i need a code coverage tool with it like clover or jacoco? issue with clover was that I am not sure how to get the report geenrated within the docker containers and make it accessible.

Comment: It provides reports and its a tool you can use as a plugin. Its easier and better to do it with the workflow i said